# Drupal cache problem, strange issue

Tags: caching, media

I have a site on Drupal 7. After migration on new server I have some issues. Site works normally and everything is ok, but after some time I can't see images, can't upload new images and don't work ajax autosave in user form.

When I use 'flush all caches' to clear cache everything works again.

What should I do? More often clear cache? Where I should looking for problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would start looking at the URL's the system is producing when the images are broken. Inspect the broken images with a DOM inspector, copy the URL pointing to the image and open that URL in a new tab. What does that say? That's your starting point I'd say.

Comment: Also check if the cron runs normally.

Comment: @thomas_x Check if you're using some external cache (such as memcached), so maybe the cache is shared with another site.

Comment: Check your files and folders ownership and permissions. Check also how Apache is running and under which username. Good luck.